# How to improve the coverage of this test class in Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have created a test class with 51% code coverage till line no 34.

Further, I tried to satisfy if condition but I couldn't. Now I am not getting how to do with 100% code coverage.

Here is the Apex class:

```
public class AssignProjectController {
public String CaseIds;
public String status {get;set;}
public List<Project__c> activeProjects {get;set;}
public String keyWordSearched {get;set;}
public Id projectId {get;set;}
public AssignProjectController (){       
    CaseIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');             
}

public void getProjects(){
 status  = '';
  String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + keyWordSearched + '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Project__c (id,Name,Description__c where Status__c =\'Active\')';
  try{
  List<List<Project__c >> searchList = search.query(searchQuery); 
  activeProjects  = searchList[0];
  if(activeProjects.size() == 0) status = 'No search result found.';
  }catch(Exception ex){
    system.debug('ex..'+ex.getMessage());
    }}}
public PageReference assignProjectToCases(){ 
    List<Case__c> customSettingList = Case__c.getall().values();
    List<String> settingRecordTypeList = new List<String>();         
    for(Case__c caseObj:customSettingList){
        settingRecordTypeList.add(caseObj.Name);
    }   
   List<RecordType> recordTypeListData = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' and Name In : settingRecordTypeList];        
    if(CaseIds != null){
        List<String> caseIDList = new List<String>(); 
        caseIDList = CaseIds.split(',');                        
        if([Select id from Case where Id In : caseIDList and RecordType.Id NOT In : recordTypeListData].size() > 0){
           status  = 'failed';
        }else{
             List<Case> cases = [Select id,Project__c,RecordType.Name from Case where Id In : caseIDList and RecordType.Id In : recordTypeListData];
             if(cases.size() > 0){
                for(case caseOb: cases){            
                    caseOb.Project__c = projectId ;
                }        
                try{
                    update cases ;
                    status  = 'Changes are scheduled';
                 }catch(Exception ex){
                    system.debug('AssignProjectController :::'+ex.getMessage());
                    status  = 'Something Went Wrong';
                }}}}
     return null;
 }}
```

Here is the test class- which I tried to resolve

```
 @isTest public class TestAssignProjectController {
public static Project__c insertProject(){
    Project__c proObj = new Project__c();
    proObj.Name = 'testProject';
    proObj.Status__c = 'Active';
    proObj.Description__c = 'for testing';
    proObj.Internal_Email_Alias__c = 'a@test.com';
    return proObj;
}
public static Account getAccount(){
    Account accoObj = new Account();
    accoObj.Name  = 'testAcc';
    accoObj.Location__c = 'testLocation';
    accoObj.Type = 'CM';
    accoObj.BillingCountry = 'United States';
    return accoObj;
}
public static Contact insertContact(Account accObj){
    Contact conObj = new Contact();
    conObj.FirstName = 'test';
    conObj.LastName = 'testLastname';
    conObj.AccountId = accObj.Id;
    conObj.Email = 'abc@gmail.com';
    return conObj;
}
 public static Id getTechTypeId(){
    return Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Tech ').getRecordTypeId();
}
public static Case insertCase(String conId, String proId){
    Case caseObj = new Case();
    caseObj.Project__c = proId;
    caseObj.ContactId = conId;
    caseObj.Status = 'Open';
    caseObj.Inquiry_Type__c = 'All'; 
    caseObj.Subject = 'TestSubject';
    caseObj.Description = 'TestDescription';
    caseObj.Case_Is_Reopened__c = false;
    caseObj.RecordTypeId = getTechTypeId();
    return caseObj;
}
public static testmethod void testMethodExecution(){
    AssignController asigncon = new AssignController ();

    Project__c proObj = insertProject();
    insert proObj;
    System.assertEquals(proObj.Status__c,'Active');
    Account accObj = getAccount();
   insert accObj;
   System.assertNotEquals(accObj.Id,null);
    Contact conObj = insertContact(accObj);
   insert conObj;
   System.assertNotEquals(conObj.Id,null);
   Case caseObj = insertCase(conObj.Id, proObj.Id);
   insert caseObj; 
   system.debug(caseObj);  
  //Set baseURL & case ID
    PageReference pageRef = Page.Assign;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id',caseObj.id+',');
    AssignController asigncon1 = new AssignController ();
    asigncon1.getProjects();
    asigncon1.assignProjectToCases();
}}
```

Comment: "I tried to satisfy if condition but I couldn't" - would you expand on that? Why could you not do that?

Comment: Can you state which `if` statement you are talking about?

Comment: This is one of my pet hates about the Salesforce platform, the near-gamification of unit test coverage. There are four 'if' statements in that class.

Each if statement can have two outcomes. Either it's true or it's not. If you truly care about the robustness of your code, you'd have at least eight test methods, each one testing what each positive and negative outcome of each 'if' did, and, better still 2^4 (16) methods, testing each potential combination of the ifs.

That way, coverage would not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring `if(cases.size() > 0)` this statement, then surely there is problem of inserting the case. Make sure that `insert caseObj;` is working and inserts data in Salesforce backend.

If there is no data in case object, the test method cannot cover the if statement.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)  nw I have resolved this problem.

Comment: @Swarnika: If my answer help you, please mark the answer as selected